# Are quasitrace extensions unique?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm trying to understand the basics of quasitraces on $C^*$-algebras. Using the terminology of [Haagerup](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.7653.pdf), given $n \geq 2$, an $n$-quasitrace $\tau$ on a $C^*$-algebra $A$ is a 1-quasitrace on $A$ which can be extended to a 1-quasitrace on the matrix algebra $M_n(A)$. It was shown by Blackadar and Handelman that any 2-quasitrace is also an $n$-quasitrace for every $n \geq 2$. The space of (normalized) 2-quasitraces on $A$ is denoted $QT(A)$.

As far as I understand, the extension of a quasitrace from $A$ to $M_n(A)$ is not necessarily unique. However, [in a paper by Toms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1688v1.pdf), he takes a quasitrace $\tau \in QT(A)$ and then applies it to elements in $M_n(A)$ for arbitrary $n$ (this is on page 4).

Are the quasitrace extensions really unique? If not, why should this be well-defined?

Comment: It's unique. Look up Haagerup's paper that you cited.

Comment: Ahh, found it. I guess I should have looked at that source a little closer. Thanks!